# How to change Redis Log timestamp format

Tags: lua, redis

I'm using lua script to run redis commands and use {{redis.log()}} in it. It prints the format as mentioned below. But I wanted to change to time format in the log. i.e dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS instead of default format (dd MMM hh:MM:ss.SSS which I assume)

Format:
[pid] date loglevel message

For instance: 
[4018] 14 Nov 07:01:22.119 * Background saving terminated with success

How can I do this?

Comment: Please indicate what you tried so far. If you'd like to get answers, show people that you already invested some time & effort into solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, no, there are no "user serviceable" knobs for this. The output to the log is always preceded by a timestamp in the hardcoded format that's specified in server.c:

```
off = strftime(buf,sizeof(buf),"%d %b %H:%M:%S.",localtime(&tv.tv_sec));
```